# Using Python to insert multiple rows into a Hive table

Tags: python, hive

Hive is a data warehouse designed for querying and aggregating large datasets that reside on HDFS.

The standard `INSERT INTO` syntax performs poorly because:

1. Each statement required a Map/Reduce process to be executed.
2. Each statement will result in a new file being added to HDFS - over time this will lead to very poor performance when reading from the table.

With that said, there is now a Streaming API for Hive / HCatalog, as detailed [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Streaming+Data+Ingest).

I am faced with the need to insert data at velocity into Hive, using Python.  I am aware of the `pyhive` and `pyhs2` libraries, but neither of them appears to make use of the Streaming API.

Has anyone successfully managed to get Python to insert many rows into Hive using the Streaming API, and how was this done?

I look forward to your insights!

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to figure this out?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, my apologies for only just noticing your question!  In the end I couldn't make this work and switched to a different technology stack: we used Apache Phoenix over HBase.  The Happybase library for Python is extremely performant when it comes to streaming inserts and the Phoenix API gives us all the query flexibility we require.  I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Hive user can stream table through script to transform that data:
ADD FILE replace-nan-with-zeros.py;

```
SELECT
  TRANSFORM (...)
  USING 'python replace-nan-with-zeros.py'
  AS (...)
FROM some_table;
```

Here a simple Python script:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import sys

kFirstColumns= 7

def main(argv):

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip();
        inputs = line.split('\t')

        # replace NaNs with zeros
        outputs = [ ]
        columnIndex = 1;
        for value in inputs:
            newValue = value
            if columnIndex > kFirstColumns:
                newValue = value.replace('NaN','0.0')
            outputs.append(newValue)
            columnIndex = columnIndex + 1

        print '\t'.join(outputs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Hive and Python

Python can be used as a UDF from Hive through the HiveQL TRANSFORM statement. For example, the following HiveQL invokes a Python script stored in the streaming.py file.

Linux-based HDInsight

add file wasb:///streaming.py;

```
SELECT TRANSFORM (clientid, devicemake, devicemodel)
  USING 'streaming.py' AS
  (clientid string, phoneLable string, phoneHash string)
FROM hivesampletable
ORDER BY clientid LIMIT 50;
```

Windows Based HDInsight

add file wasb:///streaming.py;

```
SELECT TRANSFORM (clientid, devicemake, devicemodel)
  USING 'D:\Python27\python.exe streaming.py' AS
  (clientid string, phoneLable string, phoneHash string)
FROM hivesampletable
ORDER BY clientid LIMIT 50;
```

Here's what this example does:

1.The add file statement at the beginning of the file adds the streaming.py file to the distributed cache, so it's accessible by all nodes in the cluster.

2.The SELECT TRANSFORM ... USING statement selects data from the hivesampletable, and passes clientid, devicemake, and devicemodel to the streaming.py script.

3.The AS clause describes the fields returned from streaming.py

Here's the streaming.py file used by the HiveQL example.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import string
import hashlib

while True:
  line = sys.stdin.readline()
  if not line:
    break

  line = string.strip(line, "\n ")
  clientid, devicemake, devicemodel = string.split(line, "\t")
  phone_label = devicemake + ' ' + devicemodel
  print "\t".join([clientid, phone_label, hashlib.md5(phone_label).hexdigest()])
```

Since we are using streaming, this script has to do the following:

1.Read data from STDIN. This is accomplished by using sys.stdin.readline() in this example.

2.The trailing newline character is removed using string.strip(line, "\n "), since we just want the text data and not the end of line indicator.

3.When doing stream processing, a single line contains all the values with a tab character between each value. So string.split(line, "\t") can be used to split the input at each tab, returning just the fields.

4.When processing is complete, the output must be written to STDOUT as a single line, with a tab between each field. This is accomplished by using print "\t".join([clientid, phone_label, hashlib.md5(phone_label).hexdigest()]).

5.This all occurs within a while loop, that will repeat until no line is read, at which point break exits the loop and the script terminates.

Beyond that, the script just concatenates the input values for devicemake and devicemodel, and calculates a hash of the concatenated value. Pretty simple, but it describes the basics of how any Python script invoked from Hive should function: Loop, read input until there is no more, break each line of input apart at the tabs, process, write a single line of tab delimited output.

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you for providing such a detailed and rapid response.  Reading through the script you've provided, unless I'm missing something, you are describing how to **read** data from Hive via a python script?  Whilst I've gained a lot from reading this, I actually need to **write** rows into Hive at velocity.  The tuples are being picked up and stored in a Pandas dataframe, and the need is to write them (either individually or in small batches) to Hive.  Did I miss something in your reply?