# How to run hive sql in spark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, hive, bigdata

add file `s3://nouveau3/cleanser/cleanser.py`

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ext_tbl (
    c STRING
) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
LOCATION 's3-location' 
tblproperties ('skip.header.line.count'='1');

CREATE TABLE main_tbl (schema);

INSERT INTO TABLE main_tbl 
SELECT TRANSFORM(c) 
USING 'python cleanser.py' as (schema) 
FROM ext_tbl;
```

insert query run more than 15 mnts to improve that how can I run that query in spark? s3-location has more than 50 objects(gz format)

Answer (score 0):

Approach 1 - If the query doesn't deal with too much of data and depending on the capacity of your edge-nodes you can run it directly on Spark just by login into spark-sql> shell

Approach 2 - But the spark-sql shell will not submit the query in Cluster mode it will just run on single Edge-Node and this might kill your job if Edge-Node fall short of resources.

You can write a python script which will read your query and in that u can call spark.sql("your queries"). Then you can launch this job using spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster. Here with the spark-submit command you get an option to specify the deploy-mode which should be cluster. This will leverage your entire cluster instead if just a node.

Comment: thanks, syntax error while running insert query(running in pyspark shell) will above insert query support in spark ?
spark version 2.2.0

Comment: my ultimate goal is to improve the insert query, previously running the above script as a hive job in emr cluster seems take more time even for 1gb file, pls..suggest some solutions

Comment: What does this piece of code do .. ???
`SELECT TRANSFORM(c) 
USING 'python cleanser.py' as (schema) 
FROM ext_tbl;`

Comment: remove non alpha numeric values in each row
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999696/using-python-to-insert-multiple-rows-into-a-hive-table